# How to remove the visual line from Python mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, python

I started to use Emacs for Python and I am using this package:

https://github.com/gabrielelanaro/emacs-for-python

After I install it, I see this:

[image]

There is a white line (like underscore) underneath the current line.

How can I remove this white line. it is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what modes are active in a particular buffer, type `C-h m` -- that is a shortcut for `M-x describe-mode`.  If `hl-line-mode` is enabled, the readout will look like:  `Enabled minor modes: . . . Hl-Line . . .`.

---

It looks like `hl-line-mode` is active, and the `hl-line` color is set to `:underline t`.   In the instructions on the fist page of the link you cited, it states as follows:

```
Line highlighting

You may want to enable this feature with the color you prefer,
to do so, drop one of the following lines in your .emacs

(global-hl-line-mode t) ;; To enable
(set-face-background 'hl-line "black") ;; change with the color that you like
                                       ;; for a list of colors:
                                       ;; http://raebear.net/comp/emacscolors.html
```

---

`hl-line-mode` can also be enabled locally and/or only in specific major modes using mode-hooks -- enabled looks like `(hl-line-mode 1)` and disabled looks like `(hl-line-mode -1)`.

---

If `hl-line-mode` is active in **all** major modes, then you are looking for `(global-hl-line-mode t)`.  If `hl-line-mode` is active in only specific major modes, then you are looking for `(hl-line-mode 1)`.  In either case, just remove or comment out that line of code.

---

It is also possible to enable a minor-mode globally, yet turn it off for specific major modes using mode hooks. In that case, the global setting would be placed in the `.emacs` file and a mode-hook would be used to turn it off:  `(hl-line-mode -1)`.